How to change AngularJS UI Grid cell font color during cell edition
1.Background
The following code snippet shows that it is possible to change the font color of a textarea element while it is being edited (font color changes from black to red if the word foo is typed).



angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('val', function () {
    $scope.invalidTextArea = ($scope.val === 'foo');
  });
});
.red {
  color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <textarea id="1" ng-model="val" ng-class="{'red': invalidTextArea}"></textarea>
</div>

</body>



2.Observations
2.1.AngularJS UI Grid cell formatting with cellClass
The following code snippet shows that it is possible to change the font color of an
AngularJS UI Grid cell after it has been edited (font color changes from black to red if the word foo is typed in a cell and the cell loses focus).



angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{name: ""}],
    columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'Name',
        cellClass: function (grid, row, col) {
          if (grid.getCellValue(row, col) === 'foo') {
            return 'red';
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };
});
.red {
  color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit>
    </div>
</div>

</body>



2.2.AngularJS UI Grid cell formatting with ng-class
The following code snippet shows that it is possible to change the font color of an
AngularJS UI Grid cell after it has been edited (font color changes from black to red if the word foo is typed in a cell and the cell loses focus).



angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit']).controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: [{name: ""}],
  };

  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    $scope.gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue){
      $scope.invalidCell=(newValue === 'foo');
    });
   };
});
.red {
  color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ng-class="{'red': invalidCell}">
    </div>
</div>

</body>



3.Question
How shall the code snippets in section 2.1 or 2.2 above shall be modified so that the font color of the cell changes from black to red while it is being edited (i.e. not after edition is complete / cell focus is lost)?


Probably the easiest way to achieve this are Reactive forms with form validation. But for your custom solution you probably need to trigger change detection

@Sulejman, thanks for your comment. However, the solution I am looking for needs to work in AngularJS, not Angular framework.

You should probably look at using cellTemplate and define the custom behavior from scratch instead fo using prebuilt tools in grid.
columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'Name',
        cellTemplate: `
          <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" ng-class="{'red': grid.getCellValue(row, col) === 'foo'}" >
            <div ng-if="!grid.options.enableCellEdit || !col.colDef.enableCellEdit || !row.isSelected" 
                 class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</div>
            <input ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" 
                   ng-if="grid.options.enableCellEdit && col.colDef.enableCellEdit && row.isSelected" 
                   ng-class="{'red': MODEL_COL_FIELD === 'foo'}" />
          </div>`
      }
]


Here is my suggestion using the ng-change directive to update the invalidCell value whenever the input changes. By using a text input for the row, we can capture the event when the value changes and handle it accordingly.


angular
  .module("app", ["ui.grid", "ui.grid.edit"])
  .controller("ctrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: [{ name: "" }],
      columnDefs: [
        {
          field: "name",
          cellTemplate:
            '<input type="text" ng-model="MODEL_COL_FIELD" ng-change="grid.appScope.onInputChange(row, col, MODEL_COL_FIELD)" />'
        }
      ]
    };

    $scope.onInputChange = function (row, col, newValue) {
      $scope.invalidCell = newValue === "foo";
    };
  });
.red {
  color: red;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/release/4.4.5/ui-grid.min.css"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit ng-class="{'red': invalidCell}">
    </div>
</div>

</body>



